# Why can't I view the req.body in my POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I'm trying to send a username and password from a login through Passport.js. Because passport-local reads the username and password arguments from `req.body`, I want to make sure that I am properly passing them through the `req.body` through the client-side.

When I run the following code, however, I get and empty object in the console:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send()
})
```

**Can anyone tell me why I am getting an empty object instead of the supplied username and password?**

Here is the React component I am working from:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Login = () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login'
  const postLogin = async (username, password) => {
    await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password
    })
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data))
  }

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="username" >Username:</label>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        className="form-control" 
        id="username" 
        onInput={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input 
        type="password" 
        className="form-control" 
        id="password" 
        onInput={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => postLogin(username, password)}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Here is the server-side code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.use(session({ 
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
router.use(passport.initialize())

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
  const authenticated = username === "John" && password === "Smith";

    if (authenticated) {
      return done(null, { myUser: "user", myID: 1234 });
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
}))

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.send('test GET /login')
})

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send()
})

module.exports = router;
```

*Just as a note, the server-side code is still incomplete. I have LocalStrategy filled with dummy-code. I'm just trying to understand this before I keep building it.

Comment: Have you tried adding the appropriate content type header to the request?

Comment: try to use : app.use(express.json()) on the main app

Comment: @Honorablecon Thanks for suggesting that. I do currently have that set up on the main app though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm probably exposing my ignorance, but what would be the appropriate content type header? I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch, which covers various cases including this one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I realize now what you are asking! I had to use ""'Content-Type': 'application/json'". Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to post the answer in case anyone else runs into this. @jonrsharpe's suggestion pointed me to find it.

The key was in the headers. This works:

```
const postLogin = async (username, password) => {
  await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password
    }),
    // missing part
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: You should accept your answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss agreed. It's just making me wait 2 days before I can do it. Thank you.